# Best way to Check if User already exist before Inserting to DB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

Is there a better and easier way for me to check if the user is already registered before inserting it in the DB? What I usually do is use a

- SELECT Query to Compare
- then IF Statement
- IF TRUE msgbox appears "User Already Registered"
- ELSE Insert into DB

Im creating Registration Site Using asp.net c# and sql-server as database

Comment: You can user asp.net membership/ASp.net Identity to achieve this. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Use a stored procedure to do the logic as well.

Comment: Add an `unique key` to user id field, then insert into DB. Collect sql exception for duplicated user id and display to user.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that it isn't concurrency-safe. What id 2 clients want to register "John123" at exactly the same time.

Comment: @Eric: this is a very bad way to do it. just like you wouldn't try to catch a division by zero exception if you can check the numbers begore deviding, there is no need to catch an sql exception when you can simply check agains the database first

Comment: assuming the whole thing is wrapped in a transaction. This _is_ the best way to do it. Don't attempt to put business logic in the Database

Comment: @Ewan: it's the correct steps, but in the wrong place. insisting on having no logic in the database is simply wrong.  the layers concept is not holy, and using these steps at the presentation layer will create a gap of time between the testing if a user exists and the insert attempt. in this time it is possible for another user to create it's own record with the same user name. a scenario that will lead to an exception in the best case, or a duplication of user names in the worst case. Putting this logic inside a stored procedure will not only shorten the time between the test and the insert,

Comment: @Ewan (continue): but will also save a round trip between the website and the application. a stored procedure enables you also to lock the table exlusivly so that no other insert (or even select) will be able to execute against the table (a little bit overkill in this scenario, but still possible).

Comment: @Zohar "assuming the whole thing is wrapped in a transaction" using TransactionScope for example ensures no time gap. Having no logic in the DB _is_ holy. obvs this is a very simple case, but consider you may have two databases to cover UK and US which are synced over night. you code would then want to check both before using the username

Comment: @Zohar, also consider unit testing, an app version of the site which connects to the db via a web sevice, changes to the requirements such as  'duplicate usernames are allowed if condition X applies' etc etc

Comment: @Ewan: I Strongly disagree. If it was holy, there was no need for all of the fancy options we have today with modern databases. a website that shares users information in 2 databases is not a very common thing (at least not the way you described it). unit testing is a helper tool for development. the product here is a website, and the goal is not unit tests, it's users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a procedure something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_insert_user
 @Username  VARCHAR(20)
,@Action    VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
,@UserID    INT         OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[User_Table] WHERE UserName = @Username)
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO dbo.[User_Table] (UserName)
         VALUES (@Username)

         SET @UserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
         SET @Action = 'a new user with Username = ' + @Username + ' has been added'
      END
  ELSE
      BEGIN
        SET @Action = 'a user with Username = ' + @Username + ' already exists'
      END 
END
```

Comment: I would not do it this way because you are putting business logic in the data layer.

Comment: @Ewan: This is not business logic. it is the correct way to do it, but I would simply have a boolean parameter output and deal with the text in the website itself.

Comment: The business logic in this case is "each user should have a unique username". further more, you have arguably added presentation logic by returning an error message rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: I'm not down voting though, as I know a lot of places have this database centric approach. The contention only occurs when you have a choice of places to put the logic

Answer (score 0):

This seams the best approach.
But you have to do little modifications if you work in a multithreading environment.

Or modify the select to a select for update.
Or try catch the insert and if there is an insertion error handle it.

Do not insert without testing and checking if an exception is thrown. Is not a good programming practice. The exceptions are... exceptions as the name said, not a standard approach to handle errors that you know that can be thrown.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a modern example of how to do it in code.

as I outlined in my comments there are several reasons why you should do this in code rather than on the database, even though the database option seems more attractive.

A: This is business logic "don't allow multiple users to have the same username". The datalayer should not be concerned about this, just storing and retrieving users

B: Unit testing is the most important thing in the world. you NEED to be able to test your business logic in a stateless manner. Being able to inject a mocked repository enables this.

C: The Application should not be concerned with how the storage of data is implemented. you need to be able to switch that DB out for a web service or local storage on a device etc.

D: Databases are part of the infrastructure of your app. if you get big, you'll need to have more than one, fail over, clustering, replication, backups, test boxes, UAT etc etc. each of which may be running a different version of you app at any given time. Having this logic in the DB makes deploying and managing that infrastructure harder

E: Databases do not scale easily and are a shared resource. consider the case where this logic becomes more complicated. "when the username is taken, do some hard maths" you have a web farm of 100 machines all running your app with millions of users trying to register per second. With the logic in the code, you have 100 cheap web boxes sharing the load of working out the hard sum. You can scale up by adding more Web boxes no prob. With the logic on the DB your expensive DB box is maxed out on its 32 core CPU and not answering queries

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Transactions;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    public class User {
        public String Username {get;set;}
    }

    public interface IRepository
    {
        void AddUser(User user);
        bool IsUsernamefree(User user);
    }

    public class RepositorySql : IRepository
    {
        SqlConnection conn;
        public void AddUser(User user)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into users (username) values (@usernane)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.Username);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        public bool IsUsernamefree(User user)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from users where username= @usernane", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user.Username);
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if ((int)result == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class UserRegistrationViewModel
    {
        private IRepository rep;

        public string ErrorMessage {get;set;}

        public UserRegistrationViewModel(IRepository rep)
        {
            this.rep = rep;
        }

        public bool RegisterUser(User user)
        {
            using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
            {
                if (rep.IsUsernamefree(user))
                {
                    rep.AddUser(user);
                    ErrorMessage = "";
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "the user is not free";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unit testing is the most important thing in the world? In what world is that? I've been programming for more then 16 years, and NEVER used a single unit test. I have projects still runing today that are over 10 years old, and never heard a complaint about them from any customer. saing that Unit testing is the most important thing is like saing that air tunnels are the most important thing for an airplane. guess what - it's not how the airplain acts in the air tunnle, it's how it acts in the actuall air that counts. don't forget you are selling a product, even if it's not a phisical one.

Comment: the WORLD OF PROGRAMMING! wake up and smell the coffee grandad! :) seriously though. im amazed that there are people who still dont get unit testing.

Comment: dude, QA is nice but they are not your target audience. your real target are the users.

Comment: Look, you end up with the same product both ways right? unit testing and writing testable code is about writing it faster, proving you have met requirements and being adaptable to change. Users don't want a static product these days. They benefit by a dev team being able to release quickly and bug free

Comment: I accept that, but it's **not the only way** to write fast, reusable, robust and bug free. You have to choose the correct tool to do the job. Even if a hammer is the best tool ever, it still would be a terrible choise to try to replace a flat wheel with it. That's all I'm saing.

Comment: there are 5 reasons up there why you shouldn't do it in the DB. I've yet to see one for why you should do it in the db

Comment: a: This is not business logic. it's data integrity.
b: I believe I've already covered this in the first comment to this post.

Comment: c: Wrong. the database is a part of the application. I've worked before on several applications that used more then one type of data source each, and the user was able to choose what database is he working with (oracle, sql server, even access). When you know your SQL, it's easier to write the application to be blind to the kind of data source it uses.
d: Wrong again. database clusters with fail over capabilities, replication, backups, all of these has no barring on the question if the database uses stored procedures with some logic or not.

Comment: e: No one is suggesting having the database perform heavy logic. You are taking this discussion to places it should not go. 
sql server is capable of dealing with a lot of concurrent users, with or without having basic data integrity logic inside the stored procedures.
In fact, a database with well designed stored procedures will probably do a hole lot better then a database without stored procedures where all of the sql is handed to it from outside.

Comment: Your approach is like driving a Ferrari without ever going over the 1st gear. If you only want to store and retrieve data, why not use a simple text file? Sql server is not a simple "storage" for data. it's capable of doing a lot more then just store and retrieve the data, and not using it's capabilities for the sake of keeping all of the logic out of the database and inside of the business layer is simply a misuse of your tools.

Comment: that's why you disagree with my reasons. not reasons to put it on the db.

Comment: I have answered each of your five reasons, and added one reason why I think my approach is better. I have no reason to argue with if, and even if I had, SO is not the platform to have these discussions, it's a Q & A platform, not a forum. so let's just agree to disagree about this.

Comment: let me take you up on e though. selecting from a table before inserting isnt heavy? what if im adding 1000's of users in a batch? your sproc is going to be very inefficent.

Comment: whats your reason? some database can do it. therefore you should do it in the db?

Comment: if you are adding 1000's of users in a batch, your approach will still have to test each of them individually, and will have to make 2 round-trips to the database for each user, while my approach will have to make only 1. further more, using my approach you will write a specific stored procedure to handle adding multiple users, making it more efficient. My reason is that you need to pick the correct tool for the job, and make the most of the tools you have. the 3 layers architecture is just another tool, it's not the word of the god and it's not written in stone.

Comment: the round trip is insignificant compared to running the search. Look if you disagree with n-tier architechture and unit testing Im not going to convice you. but you have to admit these thibgs are widely accepted as good ideas

Comment: A single round trip is insignificant, a million are not. And your approach still searches the database. The reason you didn't convince me is not that I disagree with your favorite architecture, it's that your arguments are week at best. I am not against n-tier nor am I against unit testing. What I am against is your religious like clinging to it, without any real good reasons. You seem to want to convince people that keeping the database as dumb as possible under any circumstances in any software is a good idea. I think you are simply wrong.

Comment: my point is that single add and bulk add are clear business cases. the logic in db solution for 'insert user (including search)' forces you to add an additional 'insert user (no search)' embedding knowledge of how the data is being used in the db. the client then has to decide which to call. if you have 'insert user' and 'get user' the business logic is purely in the client app. 'get user' and 'insert user' can be reused for many business requirements. this illustrates the fact that 'insert with check' does embed business logic and is flawed

Comment: Sorry, you have failed to demonstrate your claim yet again, Unless you want to remove the unique constraint on the username from the database, There is no good reason to leave this piece of logic out of the database. This argument is getting us nowhere. I will not convince you and you probably can't convince me. let's just drop the subject.

Comment: I challenge you to a dance off!! (and or 'rap battle')

Comment: I ignore your challenge, and will ignore any other comments on this subject. I've had enough.